reinterpret_cast to span of wrappers
Given the following wrapper (simplified):
template <std::integral T> class Wrapper {
    public:  auto val() { return t; }
    private: T t;
};

I am trying to obtain a span of wrappers to a container of the wrapped types, like:
template <std::integral T>
auto suspect(auto& ar) {
    return std::span(reinterpret_cast<Wrapper<T>*>(ar.data()), ar.size());
}

to be used like this:
auto ar = external_func_returning_container();
auto sp = suspect<int>(ar);
external_func_accepting_span_of_wrappers(sp);

(Note: My current use-case is a protobuf repeated field, but it can be any container that I have no control over).
My understanding is that since Wrapper standard layout it is possible to cast a pointer to it to a pointer to it's wrapped member.
However, I strongly suspect that the suspect() template as written invokes undefined behaviour, mostly because there are no actual Wrapper objects.
My questions are:

Am I right in believing that suspect() invokes UB?

If so, is there a way to rewrite it without invoking UB or copying a potentially large container (using C++20 or C++23 features)?

If not possible to do it in a portable way, are there any Clang-specific way to accomplish it?



Edit:
Will placement new work?
template <std::integral T>
auto suspect(auto& ar) {
    return std::span(new(ar.data()) Wrapper<T>[ar.size()], ar.size());
}

Hmmm... it appears that, according to [expr.new] (21.4), array placement new can add an unspecified overhead, so it may not work for this purpose. Or maybe I misunderstand?

Edit 2: (in response to comments and answers)
I am currently using Clang17, which does not support std::start_lifetime_as.
Actually, according to cppreference, no compiler currently supports it.
However, a SO answer suggests that it can be implemented as follows:
template<class T>
requires (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T>)
T* start_lifetime_as(void* p) noexcept
{
    return std::launder(static_cast<T*>(std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T))));
}

But it seems that I need a start_lifetime_as_array instead, and I am not sure how to implement it.

What is the value type of ar supposed to be? But whatever the answer, it is really simple: If it is not Wrapper<T>, then it is UB. Depending on what exactly the type is, maybe it will work in practice on current compilers.

Short answer: it is UB but most compilers will do the "sane" thing.

@NathanOliver That will at least depend on the type T (whether compilers will behave sanely in practice) and even then I am not sure in general.

@user17732522 T is std::integral.  For basic type the elision while UB typically does what's expected. That said I would not rely on it with production code, only just playing around.  One day it might not do the sane thing.

"C++23 features" then you should consider std::start_lifetime_as.

@NathanOliver Sorry, I missed the constraint. That avoids the worse-case scenario, but I still wouldn't 100% trust compilers to not do unintended pointer aliasing analysis here if the point of creation of the T object is visible to the optimizer.

@WeijunZhou see "Edit 2"

I'll assume that you mean that ar's value type is T.

My understanding is that since Wrapper standard layout it is possible to cast a pointer to it to a pointer to it's wrapped member.

That's correct (if T is itself standard-layout, but you are doing the other way around and if there is no Wrapped<T> object to begin with, then it doesn't matter that you could obtain a pointe to the wrapped object in that way. It simply doesn't exist.
Using the result of this cast is always UB.

Am I right in believing that suspect() invokes UB?

Yes.

If so, is there a way to rewrite it without invoking UB or copying a potentially large container (using C++20 or C++23 features)?

By applying std::start_lifetime_as to the storage of ar. However, in general, that must be implemented in the container ar or you need to apply std::start_lifetime_as again to revert back to T before the container will try to perform any non-trivial action on the memory again. After the call to std::start_lifetime_as, generally, only access through Wrapped<T> will be allowed.

If not possible to do it in a portable way, are there any Clang-specific way to accomplish it?

Not that I am aware of.

Note that compilers do definitively make use of this UB if T is not standard-layout and even if it is standard-layout I am not 100% sure that they don't. Being standard-layout the compiler can not make use of the UB when seeing a pointer to T and one to Wrapped<T> for pointer aliasing analysis. However, if it can see the origin of the pointer, it could in principle do that.

Sorry, I missed that you have a constraint of std::integral on T. Then T is of course standard-layout and the worst case scenario does not apply.

"that must be implemented in the container ar" why is that?

@WeijunZhou Not necessarily (fixed that), but in general yes (if not reverted). For example if the container holds a T* pointer into the memory, it will point to an out-of-lifetime object after std::start_lifetime_as.

@user17732522 Thank you for the answer, but please see "Edit 2"

@AlexO placement-new is not itself UB (just like the cast), but the resulting values of the objects will be indeterminate and accessing them will be UB. Your implementation of start_lifetime_as_array is valid, but consider what I wrote above about using it. Getting this correct is very tricky and is likely only possible if you write your own container for it and with non-obvious usage restrictions.

@AlexO It would be much safer and cleaner if you either made the original container to hold Wrapper<T> from the beginning or if you modified whatever code that is using the wrapper to work without it. Even if it was implemented correctly, I would very likely not accept the start_lifetime_as approach (nor any other you showed) in a code review.

@AlexO Without implementing your own container, it will pretty much end in UB for anything but std::array. That one can, with caveats, work with std::start_lifetime_as.

@user17732522 (1) the implementation is not mine, and it's of start_lifetime_as. (2) the actual container is a protobuf repeated field so I have no control over it. I will add another edit (sigh)

@AlexO It doesn't matter start_lifetime_as_array is just a convenience wrapper around start_lifetime_as. If you have no control over the interfaces at all, then there are only two solutions: Perform a copy or trust the compiler to behave as expected (in that case just reinterpret_cast is fine). There are tricks to help ensure the latter, for example if the two external functions you mention are actually located in different translation units and you do not use LTO, or they are even located in different shared libraries, you can be quite confident that the optimizer can't do anything bad.

"start_lifetime_as_array is just a convenience wrapper around start_lifetime_as" Can you suggest how to implement it?

@AlexO Sorry, not really a wrapper because of the dynamic array size, but If you are implementing it yourself anyway, something like template<class T> T* start_lifetime_as_array(void* p, size_t n) noexcept { return std::launder(static_cast<T*>(std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T)*n))); } will do.

I'm afraid that it will only start the lifetime of one (the first) object.

@AlexO No, array types are always implicit-lifetime, so memmove will create them as necessary as well. Any elements of the array (if they are themselves implicit-lifetime, which cannot be checked programmatically in C++17) will also be created implicitly as elements of the array. (Also note that implicit object creation itself was a defect report resolved with C++20, but against older standard versions as well. Before the defect report the standard did not define any way start_lifetime_as-like behavior at all.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
